# Angular won't post data to API

Tags: html, angular, api, crud, angular5

I got a problem which I dont understand.
I try to post data to my API in a form using the following code

```
formSubmit() {

  const req =this.http.post('http://[ip]/api/login', {
  id: '7',
      username: 'PostTest',
      password: 'studp123lan',
      matrikelnr: 'winf303666',
      email: 'winf303666@example.de',
      email_verified: '1'
    })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
  err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
  }
```

When I inspect it in the Chrome Developter tools, this is what I get:

```
Failed to load http://[ip]/api/login: Response for preflight has 
invalid HTTP status code 404
register.component.ts:42 Error occured
```

And this is what I get in the network tab:

General:

```
Request URL:http://[ip]/api/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[ip]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 21 Dec 2017 09:00:35 GMT
Server:Kestrel
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Request Header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:[ip]
Origin:http://localhost:4200
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36
```

Somehow, this doesn't work. But when I Post the same data via Postman Post Request to the same URL, it works like a charm.
Can anyone explain and help?
Thanks.

Comment: have you enabled cors support on your server

Comment: first off, you dont map the response (which you probably should), second, you dont return the call

Comment: You don't have to map the response if you're using the new HttpClient. And he doesn't need to map the response, because he has no response :D And he also doesn't need to return the call, if he does it in the component and uses an async pipe (bad practice I agree, but hey, we can't be perfect)

Answer (score 0):

404 is a page not found error : this means your endpoint isn't available at this address.

Sure, you make a postman call and it works : but **did you create your postman call by hand, or used the interceptor to make it ?** (The interceptor is a Chomr plugin that allows you to register all calls made by Chrome, into postman).

There must be something you have forgotten. Could you post your postman call, and if you can, try with the interceptor ?

Comment: It would greatly help if you provided your IP address (change some letters in it if you want). But having the port you requested would help : it says 80 in the remote address, but none in the the request !

Comment: it looks like its to do with how the call is done, as the call is incorrect for angular

Comment: Never said otherwise actually !

Comment: what do you mean? the call probably doesnt work in his angular app as it isnt fully how an angular http call should be made

Comment: I mean that even if it works in Postman and not in Angular, it doesn't mean that the Angular call is correctly written. He could have forgotten something, such as the port, or a header, that he didn't forgot in Postman. So having postman or an interception of it's angular call, would be far more helpful than the content of the request/response.

Comment: well you only need 2 headers for the angular call, however, he doesnt return the call or appear to set headers

Comment: Who said you only need 2 headers for an Angular call ? It depends on your endpoint, not on Angular ... And I have answered you on another comment : `You don't have to map the response if you're using the new HttpClient. And he doesn't need to map the response, because he has no response :D And he also doesn't need to return the call, if he does it in the component and uses an async pipe (bad practice I agree, but hey, we can't be perfect) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161721/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-trichetriche).